# public static final double BASE_RATE

Tags: java

Every-time I try to enter a java doc for the following code below I get the following Error Message

public static final double BASE_RATE = 100000.0;

Erro Message The Java doc for this field is missing. All visible (i.e. not private) fields require a Javadoc comment. Describe the purpose of the field and any special information about its use. If the field is not a constant, it should be private.

Comment: The reason seems to be in the error message : Write some docs for the field or make it private

Answer (score 0):

javac itself doesn't generate this error, nor does any IDE. You've turned on a setting.

Find the setting, and turn it off. Alternatively, add javadoc:

```
/** The base rate */
public static final double BASE_RATE = 100000.0;
```

Note that the above shows why you should turn that setting off. Sometimes (hopefully!) the name(s) in the signature communicate all that is there to say.